# File Transfer in Activity section is not visible

Tags: marketing-cloud

When i go to Email Studio --> Email --> Interaction --> I couldn't able to find "File Transfer " in Activity section.

I am an admin and i assigned the roles and permissions correctly.

Does anyone experience this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file transfer activity has been moved from interactions (Email Studio)to automation studio. This has not been reflected in the [Email Studio documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/) Go into Automation Studio and  Click on activities and in the right hand panel `File Transfer Activity` should be visible there (`Automation Studio > Activities > File Transfer Activities` )

[image]

**Resources**

- [File Transfer Activity (Automation Studio)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_file_transfer_activity/)